# Как с помощью одного .htaccess в корневом каталоге открыть доступ только к файлам типа index.php, но и во всех подкаталогах?

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Есть сайт с кучей подкаталогов. В каких-то из них есть файлы index.php (в том числе и в корне). Можно ли создать один файл .htaccess в корне так, чтобы во всех подкаталогах были доступны только файлы index.php?